# how to access android emulator and SDK manager without using any IDE

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to create a website in php as like as developer.samsung.com. In this User will download any of the emulator given in the list, and try their apps with that device before downloading or paying for that application.

You may please check this link:
http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action

Is it possible that i use android sdk to run the virtual device without using any IDE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In theory, you could use some fancy adb command with some prepared AVD. But it would be such a pain in the ass... Why not using Eclipse's DDMS to copy an apk to an emulator (and install a file manager too) and then install the apk on the emulator itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the sdk and avd managers directly from the android-SDK directory. You do not need an IDE to work with them. 
After you start an emulator you can connecto to it through adb. 
Take a look [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/beginners-guide-to-the-android-debug-bridge/) and [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/all-in-one-guide-to-adb/).

In theory you can achieve what you need to do but efficiency is another matter of discussion...